# How to evaluate probabilistic classification of multi-class problem

Tags: multiple-comparisons, bayes, model-evaluation

I have 3 classes $c = \{A,B,C\}$ and use a bayesian formulation to achieve a probabilistic outcome $p(c \mid x)$ based on some observation $x$. I know there is some bias in there which I haven't accounted for, so I don't know the optimal decision boundary.

The only way I can think of to evaluate or visualise the "quality" of my outcome probabilities is to either create a confusion matrix (I don't want to do this because I want to keep the probabilistic outcome since I don't know the decision boundary), or do the following:

I treat the outcome, e.g. $p_A = p(c = A \mid x)$ as a feature and evaluate how well it separates the three classes. I can visualise this with box plots or do pairwise statistical tests. However, this seems really messy for a 3-way comparison. I would have to decide which outcome ($p_A, p_B$, or $p_C$) I should use for each comparison.

I hope I made my problem clear. How would you elegantly evaluate the quality of probabilistic outcomes for multi-class problems? Thanks for your help!